# Extracting pure MPEG frames from MP3 from command line

Tags: command-line, sound

Is there a way to extract actual audio frames from MP3? (Which means also the meta data tags gonna be cut off.)

An imaginery command line:

`cat 1.mp3 | mpeg-frames-only > dump`

`cat 1.mp3 | mpeg-frames-only | md5`

P.S. I don't think converting mpeg to wav is a good idea for my case.

P.P.S. It's better if there are few solutions to be able to test them against each other.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: I think by frames you mean "audio samples" which is about the same as "uncompressed audio"

Comment: Both my goals are presented above - dump and md5. Under frames I mean _compressed_ audio - those bytes actually being played by an audio player.

Comment: You haven't actually presented an end goal yet. Why do you want this dump? Why do you want this md5? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: MD5's gonna be compared against each other to find unique and duplicated audio files. Dumps are useful while debugging.

Comment: If a file is truly duplicated (copied from the same source mp3 file) then the whole file will have the same md5sum, and if the file was not actually copied from the same source mp3 file then it's *very* unlikely that it will have exactly the same content, even if it came from the same source CD (but was compressed by a different program / with different settings). While it's not perfect (nothing will be), MusicBrainz is probably the best tool for finding duplicate audio files (even if that's not its primary purpose) http://musicbrainz.org/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library [libmpg123](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123/) includes an example code `extract_frames.c` doing the job. I have compiled it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is found (some args could be unnecessary). Looking for an alternative way still.

`mplayer 1.mp3 -vo null -dumpaudio -dumpfile dump.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

For finding duplicates, and organizing your library in general, MusicBrainz (http://musicbrainz.org/) is a great database and has a great set of tools built around it. Picard ( http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard ) is a GUI application designed to help you organize your music library which will probably be helpful in your goal of detecting duplicates.

If you want to try to script something yourself you can get the acoustic fingerprint of a file by installing `libchromaprint-tools` and running `fpcalc /path/to/file.mp3`. While I haven't found a definitive source saying so, I think there is a chance (though small) of two songs which are actually different having the same acoustic fingerprint, so you should manually check that two files are indeed duplicates before deleting one of them.

An overview of what acoustic fingerprinting is can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint

And a detailed explanation of how chromaprint works specifically can be found here:
http://oxygene.sk/lukas/2011/01/how-does-chromaprint-work/